# PHP - foreach only updates first row

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm trying to update multiple rows using a form and a foreach loop. I've tried solutions found on stackoverflow, but just can't seem to get it to work. I'm working on page project.php?id=13

My HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="project.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
<?php while($row = $shops->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="boxposition[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['box_position']; ?>" style="width: 50px;">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Order" class="btn btn-primary">
<?php endwhile; ?>
</form>
```

My PHP code (on the same page) which is executed on if(isset($_POST['update'])) :

```
$shopid = $_POST['shop'];
$boxorder = $_POST['boxposition'];

foreach ($shopid as $index => $value) {
$query = "UPDATE shops SET box_position = '".$boxorder[$index]."' WHERE id = '".$shopid[$index]."'";
$update_row = $db->update($query);
```

Unfortunately, it only updates the first row (lowest id). The very strange thing is that I get the correct values when I echo them using. E.g.:

```
echo $shopid[$index].'<br>';
echo $boxorder[$index].'<br>';
```

An example:
I update the $boxorder for 2 rows:
Row 1 (for shop 1): new value = 6 (old value was 7)
Row 2 (for shop 2): new value = 8 (old value was 5)

Using foreach to echo the result, it shows the correct values:
1 (shop id)
6 (new boxorder value)
2 (shop id)
8 (new boxorder value)

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Comment: use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to show what contains in $shopid, then it'll be easy to figure out .

Comment: var_dump($shopid) shows:

`array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "60" [1]=> string(2) "61" }`
`array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "60" [1]=> string(2) "61" }`

This seems to be correct, as my first shopid is 60, and the second one is 61

Comment: print_r($shopid) shows:
`Array ( [0] => 60 [1] => 61 ) 1`
`Array ( [0] => 60 [1] => 61 ) 1`

Comment: i hope executing the query inside the foreach loop will do the work

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm executing the query insite the foreach loop already.

Comment: if u are using PDO then just execute the query inside the loop and place the query string outside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks. Working on updating the PDO file to make this work!

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
 <?php while($row = $shops->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
        <form method="post" action="project.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="boxposition[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['box_position']; ?>" style="width: 50px;">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Order" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="project.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">

<?php while($row = $shops->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="shop[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="boxposition[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['box_position']; ?>" style="width: 50px;">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Order" class="btn btn-primary">
<?php endwhile; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, I see I've copied my code wrong. The <form> tags are outside of the while loop. I've edited my original answer.

Comment: It is not working with the form tags outside of the While loop. It was like that in my original code, and isn't working.

Comment: update foreach ($shopid as $index => $value) foreach total code

Comment: foreach is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$shopid = $_POST['shop'];
$boxorder = $_POST['boxposition'];

$query = "UPDATE shops SET box_position =? WHERE id =?";
$db->prepare($query);
foreach ($shopid as $index => $value) {
  $db->execute(array($boxorder[$index], $shopid[$index]));
}
```

This should do it. This way you prepare the statement with `?` and fill it inside your for each.

you can do it with also as the following :

```
$query = "UPDATE shops SET box_position = :position WHERE id = :id ";
$db->prepare($query);
foreach ($shopid as $index => $value) {
  $db->execute(
    array(
      ':position' => $boxorder[$index],
      ':id'      => $shopid[$index]
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get this error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE shops SET box_position = '7' WHERE id = '61'' at line 156

Comment: Oh your using pdo.. This does not support multy query, gimme a second. Updated.

Comment: I only have a select, insert, update and delete function declared using PDO. Not 'prepare' and 'execute'. Therefore I get a fatal error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare(). My functions look like this:     public function update($query){
        $update_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__); - how do I construct the prepare() and execute() function?

Comment: Sorry, really can't get it to work with your code. It makes sense, but I haven't declared the 'prepare' and 'execute' statements in PDO, and have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Seems like you have no pdo connection than, what do you store in $db ? It should be `new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","root","");` Eventually this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622038/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-databaseprepare

Comment: I have a connection, but just can't use the function prepare as I haven't declared in in my database file. I have only declared insert, update, select and delete.

Comment: Than declare it, there are many open questions on `so` which explains it. U should need prepare anyway sometimes.