# How to instantiate PDO class functionality (::prepare method) in another class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm refactoring my PHP code, so that the insertion of data into my database is kept separate from the class that creates the database connection. I'm trying to implement the Single Responsibility Principle, but transferring my code (for inserting data) to a separate class results in the PDO::prepare statement becoming an 'undefined method'.

I have tried to instantiate my database class ('DB.php') and pass the object to the class that inserts data ('Register.php').

The **DB** class:

```
<?php
class DB 
{
  public $dbServer,
         $dbUsername,
         $dbPassword,
         $dbName,

         $pdo,
         $stmt;

  function __construct($dbServer,
                       $dbUsername,
                       $dbPassword,
                       $dbName)
  {
    $this->dbServer = $dbServer;
    $this->dbUsername = $dbUsername;
    $this->dbPassword = $dbPassword;
    $this->dbName = $dbName;

    $this->connect();
  }

  public function connect()
  {
    try {
      $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->dbServer . 
                           "; dbname=" . $this->dbName, 
                                         $this->dbUsername, 
                                         $this->dbPassword);

      $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      exit("Could not connect to database: " . $e->getMessage() );
    }
  }
}
```

The **Register** class:

```
<?php
class Register
{
  public $pdo,
         $dbh,
         $stmt,
         $conn;

  function __construct(DB $pdo)
  {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    // $this->conn = $this->pdo->connect();
  }

  public function register(Validate $val)
  {  
    try {
      $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO registration(firstName, 
                   surname, 
                   email, 
                   username, 
                   password,
                   gender,
                   area) 
          VALUES(:firstName,
                 :surname,
                 :email,
                 :username, 
                 :password,
                 :gender,
                 :area)");

      $this->stmt->bindParam(':firstName', $val->firstName);
      $this->stmt->bindParam(':surname', $val->surname);
      $this->stmt->bindParam(':email', $val->email);
      $this->stmt->bindParam(':username', $val->username);
      $this->stmt->bindParam(':password', $val->password);
      $this->stmt->bindParam(':gender', $val->gender);
      $this->stmt->bindParam(':area', $val->area);

      $this->stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

My **Configuration** file:

```
<?php
$dbServer = '127.0.0.1';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'assignment';

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
  require 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
} );

$db = new DB($dbServer, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$database = new Register($db);
```

The actual **Registration** page:

```
<?php
require('core/config.php');

if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
  $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
  $surname = $_POST['surname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $area = $_POST['area'];

  $val = new Validate($firstName, $surname, $email, $username, $password, $gender, $area);
  $val->filter();

  $database->register($val);
}
?>
```

This implementation results in the following notice:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DB::prepare()

Why doesn't the PDO class communicate its in-built prepare() function to my Register class? I have viewed ['Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622038/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-databaseprepare) on Stack Overflow and sought to remedy my code:

> $this->conn = $this->pdo->connect();

(See the commented statement in my **Register** class.) However, $this->conn ends up returning a NULL instead of my database connection.

Comment: How do you instanciate `Register`? When is `prepare` called? There seems to be some important missing pieces in your samples.

Comment: your `connect` method doesn't return anything, so `null` ...  and you are not showing us how you use these classes

Comment: Thank you, @Jeto and @lagbox! I am now fully showing my classes.

Comment: `$this->pdo` in your case is an instance of `DB` (which is confusing, you should just call it `$db` or `$database`). Therefore it doesn't have a `prepare` method itself (as a PDO instance would).

Comment: Thank you so very much, @lagbox! I have added 'return $this->pdo;' to my connect() method and it now works.

Comment: And now what's the point in the Database class at all? Why can't you create a PDO instance instead?

Comment: Hey @YourCommonSense, thanks for the questions. I thought, using the SRP, that the point of my Database class was to only create instances of my database connection? Do you mean that, since PDO is itself a class, there is no need to create a Database class at all?

Comment: In its current form - yes, I believe it is not necessary. It doesn't add anything to original PDO. So you can simply create a new PDO instance in your config file. [See how to connect with PDO properly](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql) though.